# How apply dplyr functions into a list-column?

Tags: r

My `list-column`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset<-as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(6*30,1000,100),ncol=6))
cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])
mylist<-split(dataset,dataset$kmeans)
names(mylist)<-str_c('dataset',seq_along(mylist))

obj<-dataset%>%
  group_by(kmeans)%>%
  nest()
```

I try:

```
obj%>%
  summarise_if(.data,is.numeric,sum)
```

> Error: Can't convert a list to function

and

```
obj%>%
  map(~summarise_if(.data,is.numeric,sum))
```

> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
>     no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "rlang_data_pronoun"

among other attempts...

So, how do I apply `dplyr` functions into a `list-column`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is use `dplyr::pull` in list-column (`obj$data`):

```
library(tidyverse)

obj%>%
  pull(data)%>%
  map(~summarise_if(.,is.numeric,sum))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 12865. 11787. 12864. 13443. 12548. 13170.

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 11655. 12197. 11379. 10023. 10659. 11154.

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 5175. 6053. 6855. 6130. 6504. 5967.
```

Comment: if you wanted to keep your results in a list column you could do this `obj %>%
  mutate(sum_data = map(data, ~ summarise_if(., is.numeric, sum)))`